# ejb jndi lookup throws ClassCastexception only when invoked from IBM Message Broker

Tags: ejb, messagebroker

When i try to make a remote ejb jndi look up, IBM message Broker throws ClassCastexception for the factory object.
But the same code works fine for a normal local java application and junit.Why this problem occurs when called only from IBM WMB

```
Context context = new InitialContext(ejbJndiProperties);
Object factoryObj = context.lookup("SampleBeanTAFJ/remote");
return (SampleBeanRemote) factoryObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is often called by loading parts of the interface in a different classloader to the implementation classes.

I would use the env var:

IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dibm.cl.verbose=*

Then restart the broker, this will dump classloading trace to stdout / console.txt which might give you some clues.

What are the exact classes involved in the error and what jars are they stored in? Deployed to the EG or referenced via a SHARED-CLASSES? The exact details determine which classloaders should be in use here.

Comment: I have deployed my message flow to the EG.
Iam getting an instance of StatelessRemoteProxy class which iam trying to cast to my remote class.

Comment: What class specifically is it failing to find and what jar is this contained in and where is this jar?